# 4 upvotes, no downvotes, and only +16 rep bonus

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

On this post:

[Creating a queue with structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047190/creating-a-queue-with-structs-in-c/39047415#39047415)

I gained 4 upvotes. I was expecting a 40 rep upgrade, but instead I got 16. I wasn't downvoted (I have privileges to see that)

Auditing the question in details shows:

```
+16     8 mins ago  4 events     Creating a queue with structs in C
    8 mins ago  upvote   
    10 mins ago     upvote   
+6  12 mins ago     upvote   
+10     13 mins ago     upvote
```

Earlier today I got 55 with 4 upvotes and accepted answer:

```
+55     3 hours ago     5 events     strcpy is undefined in C
+10     1 hour ago  upvote   
+10     2 hours ago     upvote   
+10     3 hours ago     upvote   
+15     3 hours ago     accept   
+10     3 hours ago     upvote   
+10     4 hours ago     upvote   
+10     4 hours ago     upvote
```

First time I'm seeing that. I already gained 335 of rep today. Is there some limit? Would surprise me. A bug?

Comment: I thought `200` is our daily cap?

Comment: You've hit the daily rep limit as described in the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: "I already gained 335 of rep today"... good old times ... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are limited to 200 reputation per day, with the exception of checkmarks (+15 each) and bounties.

You hit the daily reputation limit from upvotes and therefore the post did not award the additional reputation for today. Also, to note, there is 1 downvote now (not from me, just pointing this out for the sake of observation).

Regardless, your reputation gain is pretty impressive, keep it up.

Comment: thanks for the kind answer. I have become hooked to this site. Is there any rehab programs ? :)

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? :P

Comment: I prefer sticking to real languages thanks :)

Comment: but... jquery is a... language...

Comment: @KevinB: *Library.

Comment: You know that "checkmarks" are officially called "accepts"?

Comment: Not sure if serious...